# What is this Old French Game board with 10x10 squares and dark and light circular pieces?

Tags: identify-this-game

I have this old 10x10 wooden game board with dark (black) and light (brown) circular pieces for a long time and am trying to find out a little bit about it.

The entire board with storage is approximately 14 X 17 3/4 inches. There are 18 white and 20 black pieces about 1 1/4 in diameter. The slide covers are marked

[image: 8x8 Side]
[image: 10x10 Side]
[image: Brevete SGDG closeup]

Comment: it would help a lot if you provided more information about the pieces that came with the board. Also all we will be able to do is help identify it and will not be able to help with pricing or selling it.

Comment: @jimedean by '_the slide covers are marked_' do you mean there is writing on them somewhere?

Comment: I added a picture of the marks

Comment: @jimedean; Answer updated, is there anything on the back of the board?

Comment: I added a picture, one side is 8x8, the other is 10x10

Comment: Still unsure as to the manufacturer + date, but here's a potentially older version of the same board: https://www.1stdibs.com/furniture/folk-art/game-boards/early-19th-century-french-double-sided-marquetry-game-box-checker-pieces/id-f_14039982/

Answer (score 11):

That appears to be a relatively nice double sided [International draughts](https://lidraughts.org/variant/standard)/Checkers board.

Without any further identifying information, it could have been produced anytime in the last 1-200 years, but based on its appearance, I'd estimate it was manufactured around the 1940s-1950s.

The markings indicate the board has a Breveté SGDG, which is a French patent, the Breveté SGDG system started in 1844 and ended in 1968, so that narrows the age down to a 120 year window.

Comment: I almost commented about "checkers", but the link describes the difference well that draughts is 10x10 and checkers is 8x8.

Comment: This is so interesting. In Russia we always played "checkers" on an 8x8 board but with draughts king rules. I always wondered where that came from

Comment: @Andrew T., Wikipedia uses checkers and draughts equivalently, calling [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_draughts) international draughts, international checkers and Polish draughts.